Pseudoinverses in solving a matrix equation
I have the following linear algebra equation (all letters represent matrices):
X * P = X * L * Q
All are known except Q. I want to find Q.
None of the matrices are square, but they are pseudo-invertable, so I thought that I would multiply by pinv(X) on the left and then by pinv(L) on the left to get
Q = pinv(L) * P
However, this doesn't work (code attached). Why? Is this equation not solvable in general, or for the given matrix sizes?
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def get_random( r, c ):
    return np.random.random(( r, c ))

x = get_random( 300, 20 )
l = get_random( 20, 5 )
p = get_random( 20, 100 )

q = np.linalg.pinv( l ) @ p

# verify that pseudoinverses work

xx = np.linalg.pinv( x ) @ x
ll = np.linalg.pinv( l ) @ l

assert np.allclose( xx, np.eye( xx.shape[0] ))  # PASS
assert np.allclose( ll, np.eye( ll.shape[0] ))  # PASS

#

ret_p = x @ p
ret_q = x @ l @ q

assert np.allclose( ret_p, ret_q )              # FAIL

plt.figure( 1 )
plt.imshow( ret_p )

plt.figure( 2 )
plt.imshow( ret_q )

plt.figure( 3 )
plt.imshow( ret_p - ret_q )

plt.show()


It it doesn’t work, the equation is not solvable.

You are correct in using the pseudo-inverse.
If we consider the given equation:
$$XP = XLQ$$
then by applying the pseudoinverse of $X$ we obtain the constraint:
$$X^{+}XP = X^{+}XLQ \implies P = LQ.$$
The reason your code fails is because it doesn't enforce the restriction that $P = LQ$. In order to achieve this we need to factor $P$ in our construction of the problem.
Any real-valued matrix, $P$, can be decomposed as two matrices (QR Factorization):
$$P = LQ.$$
Applying this to your problem, we can use numpy.linalg.qr() and simulate the equation as follows:
import numpy as np

m = 2
n = 3
p = 4
q = 5

X = np.random.random((m, n))
P = np.random.random((n, p))

L, Q = np.linalg.qr(P)

assert np.allclose(X@P, X@L@Q)
assert np.allclose(np.linalg.pinv(L)@P, Q)



I appreciate being reassured about the pseudoinverses, however I don't follow how QR factorization relates to my question. Also, this doesn't explain why my code fails the assertion. Have you run it on your computer and have it pass?

@Nucular Sorry, I was a unclear about your code. I added some edits that should make the explanation clearer.

L is given, and it does not come from a QR decomposition or an LQ decomposition (in case the letters are misleading).

I am just using QR factorization in order to simulate your problem. The reason your code fails is because it fails to simulate the problem correctly. In order to simulate the problem, you must meet the condition P = LQ. You can't just simulate it by declaring L and P as random matrices. L is a factor of P.
